# Mysql- MyISAM how Multi threading works

Tags: mysql, myisam

How Multithreading works with MyISAM. as it supports Table level locking?
If we request select from same table. How threading works in this scenario

Comment: Too broad and off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate connections get separate threads.  A single connection will not use multiple threads.  (MyISAM and InnoDB)

When two separate connections (threads) try to access the same table at the "same" time, some kind of locking happens.

`SELECT` acquires a read lock, which prevents writes, but not other reads.  (MyISAM)

`INSERT` and other writes acquire a write lock, preventing anything (writes or reads) from working with the table.  (MyISAM)

When a connection is blocked, it waits, then eventually runs.  (MyISAM)

InnoDB, with its row-level locking (and no table-level locking) allows more concurrency, but has other complexities.

Without a good reason, everyone should move from MyISAM to InnoDB.